# In functional programming, is there a clean way to perform many operations on some data without having to explicitly pass the data into each function?

Tags: functional-programming, monads

Let's say that I have a few functions that perform business logic on some data:

```
function addEmployees(data, numberOfNewEmployees){
    // Business logic...
    data.employeeCount += numberOfNewEmployees;
    return data;
}

function withdrawFunds(data, withdrawAmount){
    // Business logic...
    data.checkingAccount -= withdrawAmount;
    return data;
}

function completeAnOrder(data){
    // Business logic...
    data.pendingOrders -- 1;
    return data;
}
```

Now, to do several operations on some data, I have something like this (Let's assume that data is passed by copy):

```
const data = {
    employeeCount: 5,
    checkingAccount: 5000,
    pendingOrders: 2
}

let newData = addEmployees(data, 2);
newData = withdrawFunds(newData, 2000);
newData = completeAnOrder(newData);
```

I was curious if there is an elegant method in the functional programming world to accomplish something closer to this:

```
const data = {
    employeeCount: 5,
    checkingAccount: 5000,
    pendingOrders: 2
}

let biz = createBiz(data);

const newData = biz.addEmployees(2)
    .withdrawFunds(2000)
    .completeAnOrder()
    .toValue();
```

In JavaScript I know that an object can return `this` and that is how JQuery method chaining works.

But is there a elegant method in the functional world to do something similar? I realize I may be trying to force an OOP idea into FP.

Is there a Monad that solves this problem? Does it make sense to create your own custom Monads for specific business logic?

Comment: Chaining has nothing to do with `this`. You just need to return an object - *any* object - that you can call a method on. Of course, in functional programming you'd rather return a new object instead of mutating the input, but that's an orthogonal issue.

Answer (score 1):

This will heavily depend on the language and the tools the language has available.

In [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), which is [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), tasks like this are often solved using macros. In this case, this would be accomplished using a "threading" macro.

Say I have your functions:

```clj
;  All of these functions return the modified data
(defn add-employees [data number-of-new-employees]
  ...)

(defn withdraw-funds [data withdraw-amount]
  ...)

(defn complete-an-order [data]
  ...)
```

Since "this" (the `data`) is the first parameter, I can use `->` to automatically "thread" the argument to each call:

```clj
(def data {:employee-count 5,
           :checking-account 5000,
           :pending-orders 2})

(-> data
  (add-employees 2) ; The result of this gets passed as the first argument to withdraw-funds
  (withdraw-funds 2000) ; Then the result of this gets passed to complete-an-order...
  (complete-an-order) ; Same as above
  (to-value))
```

After macro expansion, this basically gets turned into:

```clj
(to-value (complete-an-order (withdraw-funds (add-employees data 2) 2000)))
```

But it's much more readable and easier to change in the future using `->`.

Answer (score 0):

You would use composition.  In Haskell, if the operations are pure functions that operate on a structure and return a new structure, and not I/O operations, you might write that several different ways, such as: `toValue . completeOrder . withdrawFunds 2000 . addEmployees 2 $ data`.  (You can also write it left-to-right using `&`.)

You’re more likely to see that example turned into stateful code with side-effects on an external database, though.  In Haskell, this would use the abstraction of applicatives or monads, but most other functional languages wouldn’t be such sticklers for mathematical formalism.  The applicative version lets you write something like `runValue $ completeOrder <$> withdrawFunds 2000 <$> addEmployees 2 <$> data`.  Or you can write this as `do` blocks.

Facebook gives [some real-world examples](https://code.facebook.com/posts/302060973291128/open-sourcing-haxl-a-library-for-haskell/?_fb_noscript=1) of how it does this for some of its database code.  The imperative code:

```
NumCommonFriends(x, y) = Length(Intersect(FriendsOf(x), FriendsOf(y)))
```

has the applicative version

```
numCommonFriends x y =
  length <$> (intersect <$> friendsOf x <*> friendsOf y)
```

which can be written with some syntactic sugar as

```
numCommonFriends x y = do
  fx <- friendsOf x
  fy <- friendsOf y
  return (length (intersect fx fy))
```